# Função que retorna múltiplos elementos

Tags: c, array, funções

Estou com um duvida no seguinte exercício:

Faça uma sub-rotina que receba um único valor representando segundos. Essa sub-rotina deverá convertê-lo para horas, minutos e segundos. Todas as variáveis devem ser passadas como parâmetro, não havendo variáveis globais.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ConverterSegundos(int seg) {
    int hr, min, segundos, res[3];

    res[0] = hr = (seg / 60) / 60; //Calculo das horas
    res[1] = min = (seg / 60) % 60; //Calculo dos minutos
    res[2] = segundos = seg % 60; //Calculo dos segundos

    return res[0];
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int segundos,horario[3];

    printf("Digite os segundos: ");
    scanf("%d", &segundos);
    horario[0] = ConverterSegundos(segundos);

    printf("Conversão para o formato %d:mm:ss \n",horario[0]);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

O problema vem na hora de retornar os valores,como são 3 valores pensei em armazena-los em um vetor com 3 posições e retorna-lo,bom o problema que não estou conseguindo fazer isso. Não sei como faço para imprimir cada posição individualmente do vetor retornado.

**OBS: Ainda não vi ponteiros.**

Comment: Tecnicamente o enunciado não pede para retornar nada.

Comment: Mas enfim, não retorne um vetor que foi declarado dentro da função. Se não sabe lidar com ponteiros ou alocar memória no heap, melhor não retornar nada e imprimir horas, minutos e segundos de dentro da sub-rotina. Aliás, o conceito de sub-rotina geralmente implica que não retorna nada (enquanto "função" retorna).

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado amigo, vou printar dentro da própria sub-rotina msm

Comment: Veja também a resposta no link de duplicata que marquei. Lá explica como "retornar" array (passar um ponteiro para array ou alocar memória na mão).